# How to show existing form from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have Form1 and Form2, in Form1 i have some textboxes like username,password and more... and a textbox "region". when user hits "region"(Form1.hide()), then Form2 opens witch has 5 labels with names of regions on it.

so how can i make that when user clicks on a name of region in Form2, Form1 will have the region on it? and keep all the data that the user entered before the region click.

something like this(in form 2):

```
private void center_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1.region = "center";
        Form1.show();
    }
```

Comment: You just need to subscribe the form's FormClosing event.  When it fires, and e.Cancel is false, then you know it is about to die so it is a good idea to call this.Show(). Beware that FormClosed sounds like a better idea, but it is too late and the window of another app might get the focus.  Also do note that not many apps you use every day do this, they usually have one main window and switch content inside the window.  Like UserControl helps you do.

Answer (score 0):

On Form 2

```
private void center_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.textbox_region = whateverobject.text;
    this.hide();
    frm1.show();
}
```

this will bring up a form1 with the region text on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an instance of Form2 and calling `ShowDialog()` method to show it

```
Form2 form2= new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating Form2, just pass Form1 as a parameter and edit the textbox value in your click event.

On form1:

```
private void click_on_region(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
    Form2.Show();
}
```

on form2:

```
Form1 _frm1;
public Form_Main(Form1 frm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _frm1 = frm;   
}
private void center_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    _frm1.textBox_region.Text = whateverobject.Text;
    _frm1.Show();
}
```

This might not be the prettiest but It'll do for starters.

Answer (score 0):

**Form 1 Code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
        objForm2.ShowDialog();
        textBox_Region.Text = objForm2.RegionName;
    } 
 }
```

**And Form 2 Code**

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
 {
    public string RegionName
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox_Form2_Region.Text.ToString();
        }
        set { }

    }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```